# PROD and DEV CSS not similarly rendered with Nuxt3

Tags: css, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxt3

I built a Vue3 component library (let's call it MY-LIBRARY) with Nuxt3, using among others tailwind v2.
I have a side project called MY-SIDE-PROJECT built with laravel-mix (v6) and Vue3, that uses tailwind v2.
I also have another Vue3 project (let's call it My-PROJECT) built with Nuxt3, also using tailwind v2.

In MY-PROJECT I use components from MY-LIBRARY to render pages.

When I build MY-PROJECT in production using the `npm run build` script that triggers `nuxt build`, my pages are served but I have warnings in my console such as:

```
 [WARNING] CSS nesting syntax is not supported in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14") [unsupported-css-nesting]

    <stdin>:1:62181:
      1 │ ...-cell}@media (min-width:1024px){&--bordered-max-lg,&--hidden-max...
        ╵
```

**Edit: this problem is solved, MY-LIBRARY's css was not correctly bundled.**

**STILL, the CSS is not correctly interpreted in MY-PROJECT's pages.**

I expect MY-PROJECT's pages to correctly serve the CSS from MY-LIBRARY as it builds in production.

I already tried to play with nuxt's config in MY-PROJECT, but the combo Nuxt3/Vue3 along with tailwind v2 is not well documented on the internet. I cannot really move to tailwind3 for the moment as this project has some external compatibility requirements.

Here is MY-PROJECT's nuxt.config.js file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ...
    css: [
        '@/assets/styles/main.scss'
    ],
    postcss: {
        plugins: {
            tailwindcss: {},
            autoprefixer: {},
        },
    },
    build: {
        postcss: {
            postcssOptions: {
                plugins: {
                    tailwindcss: {},
                    autoprefixer: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Here is MY-PROJECT's tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    important: true,
    presets: [
        require('MY-LIBRARY/tailwind.config')
    ],
    purge: {
        content: [
            "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
            "./pages/**/*.vue",
            "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
            "./app.vue",
        ]
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {
            ...
        }
    },
    variants: {
        ...
    }
}
```

I already tried adding a postcss.config.js in MY-PROJECT but it didn't change anything.

If you have any advice on how I could solve my issue I would be so grateful!!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
After trying out a few things, it appears the main problem is that the commands `npm run dev` (run locally) and `npm run build; npm run start` (when deployed, but I also reproduce locally) do not render equally. CSS is not similarly rendered. Here is MY-PROJECT's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MY-PROJECT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --port=3000",
    "docker": "npm run dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "start": "nuxt start"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "MY-LIBRARY": "^1.1.2",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.3.1",
    "nuxt-proxy": "^0.4.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.33",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.17",
    "ufo": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue3-lottie": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "4.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "vue": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are targeting browsers which don't support CSS nesting, see the [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=nesting). Did you consider to use a preprocessor like SCSS? Until all the browsers support this natively, I think this is the best alternative.

Comment: I already added sass and sass-loader as dependencies in MY-PROJECT, I'm not sure what I can do more about that?

Comment: In this case, either you are using the `.css` extension while you should use `.scss`, or your webpack config is not correct. However it's hard to tell without a reproduction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried renaming my main.css into main.scss, and I checked that MY-LIBRARY's SCSS is correctly bundled into CSS. But still the same issue.
After trying out a few things, it appears the main problem is that the commands `npm run dev` (run locally) and `npm run build; npm run start` (when deployed, but I also reproduce locally) do not render equally. CSS is not similarly rendered. I'll edit my original post to add my package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem was.
In my tailwind config, I needed to specify that I also wanted to apply tailwind to the components imported from MY-LIBRARY.

Thanks @JSONDerulo for the exchanges that allowed me to pinpoint the origin.

```
#MY-PROJECT's tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    important: true,
    presets: [
        require('MY-LIBRARY/tailwind.config')
    ],
    purge: {
        content: [
            "./components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}",
            "./pages/**/*.vue",
            "./nuxt.config.{js,ts}",
            "./app.vue",
            "./node_modules/MY-LIBRARY/components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}" #<-- the important part
        ]
    },
    theme: {
        extend: {
            ...
        }
    },
}
```